# Clarification on previous post , Geohashing string length and accuracy?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geo, geohashing

Hello I'm a little confused about the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448595/geohash-string-length-and-accuracy). The answer says that by increasing the length of the string you can increase the accuracy, which I understand. What I don't understand is how he is getting the numbers for the accuracy that he gets. He goes from a 110km x 110km to a 10km x 10km area by adding a digit. I want to get a 5m x 5m area. Can some give a more in depth explanation of how he got these figures.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, he is talking about the accuracy of a specified point.

For example if we have a Location which we are interested, and we have two points defining that same location
- point1(156.34,-23.34), and 
- Point2(156.342,-23.343)

So effectively the first point is somewhere between  Latitude (156.335 - 156.344), Logitude (-23.335 - -23.344), and the second point  Latitude (156.3415 - 156.3424) and Logitude (-23.3425 - -23.3434).

Basically normal GPS might get to near that 5 meter accuracy, though most often its anyway going to be less accurate, thus, what you need to to, is simply to use the whole value you get from the positioning module.